# Out of range vector subscript C++

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, subscript, outofrangeexception

I have this method in one of my cpp files where I have navigated my failure to be. I have also added cout statements and checked that there is content in both foo and mainWord. I think my problem has to do with how I've added elements to foo or how I am trying to re-add them. The size mainWord is 88 and the size of foo is more than 1000. Here is where I add elements to foo:

```
while (myfile>>magic)//store the colours in an array
{
     foo.push_back(magic);
}
```

and here is where I try and change them and add them back in.

```
void Penguin::addWord(std::vector<int> foo)
 {
 unsigned fooCounter=0;
 int temp;
for (int i=0;i<88;i+2)
 {
     if(foo.at(fooCounter) == 11111111 && foo.at(fooCounter) != NULL)
     {
         if(mainWord[i]==1 && mainWord[i+1]==1)
         {
             foo.at(fooCounter) = 11111111;
         }
         else if(mainWord[i]== 1 && mainWord[i+1] == 0)
         {
                 foo.at(fooCounter) = 11111110;
         }
         else if(mainWord[i]== 0 && mainWord[i+1] == 1)
         {
             foo.at(fooCounter) = 11111101;
         }
         else
        {
                 foo.at(fooCounter) = 11111100;
        }
     }
     else if (foo.at(fooCounter) == 11111111 && foo.at(fooCounter) != NULL)
     {
         if(mainWord[i]== 1 && mainWord[i+1] == 1)
         {
             foo.at(fooCounter) = 00000011;
         }
         else if(mainWord[i]== 1 && mainWord[i+1] == 0)
         {
             foo.at(fooCounter) = 00000010;
         }
         else if(mainWord[i]== 0 && mainWord[i+1] == 1)
         {
             foo.at(fooCounter) = 00000001;
         }
         else
        {
            foo.at(fooCounter) = 00000000;
         }
     }
     fooCounter++;
 }

}
```

I keep getting an error that says: "Debug Assertion Failed. Vector subscript out of range" 
...Please help

Comment: `for (int i=0;i<88;i+2)` How do you check that your vector at least contains 44 elements?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, 89, since the step is 2.

Comment: @G.Samaras It's actually less (44) because `fooCounter` is the compromised index.

Comment: In addition to this, you're passing `foo` by value.  So all of that work you're doing inside the function to change `foo` goes down the drain once the function returns.  Pass `foo` by reference, not by value.

Comment: You are correct @PaulMcKenzie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because `i` is never updated in the `for` loop. You need to fix the typo:

```
for (int i=0;i<88;i+=2)
                    ^
                    ^
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner, thank you @Mark Ransom